# TypeError: string indices must be integers. when try access the json variables

Tags: python, json

Please help me with this.

This is my json file:
abc.json

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "id": 123,
  "header": "timestamp id name"
}
```

In python script when i try to access the json variable like
col_names = data['header'] and print the data into csv file.
But i get the error now as TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Please can anyone help me with this. It would be very greateful. Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using.

Comment: Help us help you - share your code

Comment: Is the JSON composed of multiple values like that and nested within square brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

f = open('data.json')

data = json.load(f)

print(data['header'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `ast.literal_eval` in order to write values of `header` key only such as

```
import json
import ast

with open('abc.json') as f, open('abc.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        val = data[i]['header']
        f_out.write(''.join(format(val))+ '\n')
```